# Android MapView custom markers are all the same size

Tags: android, android-mapview, google-maps-markers, itemizedoverlay

I am writing an app that will show a map with a bunch of markers on it.  I want the markers to be dynamic (showing dynamic content on them).  Because the markers content is dynamic the size of each marker is different.

I found this in the documentation saying that "Different markers can be returned for different states. The different markers can have different bounds." here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/OverlayItem#getMarker(int)

I assume that means that multiple markers on the same overlay can be different sizes.  Is that correct?

I have an ArrayList on my overlay (extends BalloonItemizedOverlay).  The overlay's createItem() method looks like this:

```
@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(final int index)
{
    final Person person = people.get(index);
    final GeoPoint gp = new GeoPoint(person.getLat(), person.getLng());

    final OverlayItem oi = new OverlayItem(gp, person.getName(), person.getName());
    oi.setMarker(new PersonDrawable(defaultMarker, person));

    return oi;
}
```

Then in my `PersonDrawable` there is a drawable that has a 9 patch as a background image, and then drawing text on top of it:

```
public PersonDrawable(final Drawable iBackground, final Person person)
{
    background = iBackground;
    text = person.getName();
    padding = new Rect();

    if (background instanceof NinePatchDrawable)
    {
        // This is getting hit, and just sets the value of the padding
        final NinePatchDrawable ninePatch = (NinePatchDrawable) background;
        ninePatch.getPadding(padding);
    }

    // set the bounds of the marker
    bounds = background.getBounds();

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
    paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
    paint.setTextSize(30);

    // find the bounds of the text
    final Rect textBounds = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textBounds);

    // set the left and right bounds to that of the text plus the padding (then center it)
    bounds.left = 0 - (textBounds.width() / 2) - padding.left;
    bounds.right = 0 + (textBounds.width() / 2) + padding.right;

    // set the bounds of the drawable
    setBounds(bounds);
}

@Override
public void draw(final Canvas canvas)
{
    // when it's time to draw, draw the background
    background.draw(canvas);
    // then draw the text within the padding
    canvas.drawText(text, bounds.left + padding.left, bounds.bottom - padding.bottom, paint);
}
```

Each marker has a distinct bounds set, even after it's drawn on the overlay its bounds are distinct.  The `MapView` (or `Overlay`) is not reusing the objects from `createItem()`.  However the `Overlay` seems to always pick one marker and assume that is the size for all the markers.  Is that just the behavior?  Is there something I can do to make it respect the bounds differently for each marker?

Here are some pictures, when it decides to pick a larger marker things turn out ok:

[image: Wolverine is longer so things look alright]

However when it chooses to use the smaller marker as the size:

[image: Beast is a little shorter and overflow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when a `Drawable` is loaded from resources, it is treated as a shareable resources. From the `Drawable` documentation:

> By default, all drawables instances loaded from the same resource share a common state; if you modify the state of one instance, all the other instances will receive the same modification.

In the `OverlayItem`, it is assuming that the `Drawable` is going to be the same size throughout. The effect you are seeing is that the last modification to the `Drawable` is overriding all previous modifications, so all displays of the `Drawable` are showing up exactly the same.

The solution is to prevent sharing of the `Drawable`'s modifications. You can do this using the `mutate()` method in conjunction with multiple loads of the Drawable from a resource. You should do this in conjunction with the `PersonDrawable` constructor you have outlined above.

Comment: All the thing @Nick Campion says is true.  However calling `mutate()` was not the thing that fixed my problem.  The problem was having an `Overlay` carry one reference to a `Drawable` as the background of the marker.  Once I retrieved a new instance of the background for each marker, the sizes were as I expected them.  Regardless, thanks Nick for pointing me in the right direction!